# Как в instantcms открыть права гостю

Tags: php, cms, instantcms

Здравствуйте мне необходимо открыть права для гостя, чтобы он мог добавлять информацию на сайт. Пробовал через пу сайтом бесполезно, при заходе на страницу добавления материала требует регистрацию,может есть еще какие варианты? Спасибо.

Comment: http://www.instantcms.ru/blogs/vse-ob-instantcms-2/vklyuchenie-redaktirovanija-prav-gostei-v-administratorskoi.html

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov пробовал, поиском нашел эту информацию в интернет, появилась группа Гости, появилась возможность поставить галочку добавлять материал гостю. Но при заходе на страницу все равно выскакивает авторизация.